# How to create vector with defined names and values in R?

Tags: r, vector, match, return-value

I have a vector with names of vectors

```
LX <- c("l.1","l.2","l.3","l.4","l.5","l.6","l.7")
```

and vector of values
`LQ <- c(2,5,5,5,7,7,5)`

so that after calling i.e. l.1, I get 2, and l.7, I get 5, and so on.
I have tried to match it, but unsuccessfully. I got

```
names(LQ) <- LX
LQ
 l.1  l.2  l.3  l.4  l.5  l.6  l.7  l.8  l.9 l.10 
   2    5    5    5    7    7    5    3    3    3
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: You can acces items of named vector like this: ` LQ["l.1"]`

Comment: Where do the 3s at the end of LQ in your last code block come from? Please try and make your code consistent with itself!

Comment: I'm not sure of what are you asking. My guess is that you want your vector with names `l.2 l.5 l.5 ...`. Am I right? If that's what you want, you can get it using `names(LQ)<-LX[LQ]` . @BenBolker's is also a good answer, and you don't need to define LX.

Comment: just guessing ... do you want `names(LQ) <- paste("l",LQ,sep=".")` ?

Comment: I will try to explain it better. I have 2 vectors LQ and LX and I want to create vector with name    LX[1] including value(s)     LQ[1], so  when I type l.1   , I get value 2.  l.1<-c(2) and    l.2<-c(5)

Comment: Don't create variables from character names. Its wrong, 99 times out of 100. You should nearly always create a structured object like a list or a vector, and if this is the 1 in 100 case when you should create them, you should know why and not have to ask.

Comment: Did you think something like this?                             LQ.list<-as.list(LQ)
names(LQ.list)<-LX
LQ.list